# ViewBag ViewData and Session values are not accessible from the View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, viewbag

I have tried to use all the above methods to store a value in the controller method, after which I give a call to the partial view.

The problem here is the value that I had stored earlier gets flushed.

I need to persist that value. What should i do?

Comment: public ActionResult test(){@ViewBag.Test = "xyz" return PartialView("_testPV") }

Comment: cannot access ViewBag's value. Similarly even if i take ViewData or Session,i am not able to access the value that I have stored